# Question about asynchronous JavaScript with Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here I have a function that takes an array of string that contains the user names of github accounts. And this function is going to return an array of user data after resolving. There should be one fetch request per user. and requests shouldn’t wait for each other. So that the data arrives as soon as possible. If there’s no such user, the function should return `null` in the resulting array.

An example for the input would be `["iliakan", "remy", "no.such.users"]`, and the expected returned `promise` after resolving would give us `[null, Object, Object]`, `Object` being the data that contained info about a user.

Here is my attempt to solve this question.

```
function getUsers(names) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const array = [];
    const url = "https://api.github.com/users/";
    const requests = names.map(name => {
      const endpoint = `${url}${name}`;
      return fetch(endpoint);
    });
    Promise.all(requests).then(reponses => {
      reponses.forEach(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          response.json().then(data => {
            array.push(data);
          });
        } else {
          array.push(null);
        }
      });
      resolve(array);
    });
  });
}
```

It does work, i.e. returning an array `[null, Object, Object]`. And I thought it fulfilled the requirements I stated above. However, after looking at it closely, I felt like I couldn't fully make sense of it.

My question is, look at where we resolve this array, it resolved immediately after the `forEach` loop. One thing I don't understand is, why does it contain all three items when some of the items are pushed into it asynchronously after the `json()` is finished. what I mean is, in the case where  `response.status === 200`, the array is pushed with the data resolved from `json()`, and I would assume this  `json()` operation should take some time. Since we didn't resolve the array after `json()` operation is finished, how come we still ended up with all data resolved from `json()`?

```
 Promise.all(requests).then(reponses => {
          reponses.forEach(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              response.json().then(data => {
                array.push(data); <--- this should take some time 
              });
            } else {
              array.push(null);
            }
          });
          resolve(array); <--- resolve the array immediately after the `forEach` loop
        });
      });
```

It looks to me like the array we get should only have one `null` in it since at the time it is revolved, the `.json()` should not be finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the result is pushed later into the array.

Try to execute this:

```
const test = await getUsers(['Guerric-P']);
console.log(test.length);
```

You'll notice it displays `0`. Before the result is pushed into the array, its length is 0. You probably think it works because you click on the array in the console, after the result has arrived.

You should do something like this:

```
function getUsers(names) {
    const array = [];
    const url = "https://api.github.com/users/";
    const requests = names.map(name => {
            const endpoint = `${url}${name}`;
            return fetch(endpoint);
        });
    return Promise.all(requests).then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(x => x.status === 200 ? x.json() : null)));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how can I ensure that before resolving, the array gets filled up properly?

Comment: @Joji I've provided a one-liner solution

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using the `Promise`  constructor directly. Here, we don't need to use it at all.

```js
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/";

const getUsers = names =>
    Promise.all(names.map(name =>
        fetch(url + name).then(response =>
            response.status === 200 ? response.json() : null)));

getUsers(["iliakan", "remy", "no.such.users"]).then(console.log);
```

The `Promise` constructor should only be used when you're creating new kinds of asynchronous tasks. In this case, you don't need to use the `Promise` constructor because `fetch` already returns a promise.

You also don't need to maintain an array and push to it because `Promise.all` resolves to an array. Finally, you don't need to map over the result of `Promise.all`. You can transform the promises returned by `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that because `json()` operation is really quick, especially if response data is small in size it just has the time to execute. Second of all as objects in JavaScript passed by reference and not by value and `Array` is a object in JavaScript, independently of execution time it'll still push that data to the array even after it was resolved.